Having a classloading problem in application mode
I'm changing the deploy mode of my Flink jobs on a Yarn cluster from session mode to application. I have a bunch of jobs implemented identically, and all of them run okay except for two of them.
In session mode all my jars are working well.
In application mode I'm encountering a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class error:
2024-04-17 10:06:16,055 ERROR com.company.project.jobs.MyClassName$                 [] -  ==>> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.company.project.avro.POJOname
    sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:156)
    java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
    java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
    java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroFactory.getSpecificDataForClass(AvroFactory.java:166)
    org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroDeserializationSchema.checkAvroInitialized(AvroDeserializationSchema.java:154)
    org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroDeserializationSchema.java:135)
    com.company.project.jobs.MyClassName$$anonfun$transformStream$1.apply(MyClassName.scala:47)
    com.company.project.jobs.MyClassName$$anonfun$transformStream$1.apply(MyClassName.scala:31)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream$$anon$4.map(DataStream.scala:648)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:38)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ChainingOutput.pushToOperator(ChainingOutput.java:99)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ChainingOutput.collect(ChainingOutput.java:80)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ChainingOutput.collect(ChainingOutput.java:39)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask$AsyncDataOutputToOutput.emitRecord(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:196)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.source.SourceOutputWithWatermarks.collect(SourceOutputWithWatermarks.java:110)
    org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter$SourceOutputWrapper.collect(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:65)
    org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:84)
    org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:51)
    org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:51)
    org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:32)
    org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:143)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:354)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:495)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:203)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:806)
    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:758)
    org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:937)
    org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
    org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Flink: 1.14.6
language: Scala
running like this:
"${FLINK_HOME:?}"/bin/flink run-application -d \
      -t yarn-application \
      -Dclassloader.resolve-order=parent-first \
      -Dyarn.application.name="${1^^}" \
      -Dyarn.application.queue=root.queue.name \
      -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots="$slots" \
      -Dtaskmanager.memory.process.size="${mem}m"\
      -Dyarn.ship-files="${HOME}/conf/${1,,}.properties" \
      -p "${parallelism:?}" \
      hdfs://nNode/.../lib/prefix-${context,,}-${jar_version}.jar \
        --job_props_path "${1,,}.properties"

Avro lib in the fat jar normally ("org.apache.flink" % "flink-avro" % flinkVersion)

What am I doing wrong?
Why are all the other jobs running well, but these two are not?

Any help will be appreciated.

I figured it out. My problem was with libraries. I've added a conf yarn.provided.lib.dirs to my run command and cleaned libraries in lib/ folder leaving only default ones.
...
-Dyarn.provided.lib.dirs="hdfs://nNode/user/doe/flink14/lib"
...

Without this Yarn option, flink used local lib/ folder, which contained Hive libraries that caused problems.
hive-exec-1.1.0.jar
hive-metastore-1.1.0.jar
flink-connector-hive_2.11-1.14.6.jar
libfb303-0.9.2.jar

